# Add option to a select element on a Bootstrap 4 modal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select element in a Bootstrap 4 modal:

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Ad" class="col-form-label">Ad</label><br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class=" col-md-6">
                                <select id="ADSelect" class="form-control" title="Choose one of the following origin..."></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="or add a new one" id="Ad">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I add the options to the select element using this function:

```
function GetAD() {

$('#ADSelect').empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Default.aspx/GetAD',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                var select = document.getElementById("ADSelect");
                option.value = data.d[i];
                option.text = data.d[i];
                select.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
})
```

}

I call this function on  $(document).ready() and it works just fine. When the modal gets open the select element has all the options no problem. Now a new value is entered on the modal and it’s get save on database and the modal closed. Next time the modal is open this new value should be on the select. I tried these two option :

```
    $('#ComplaintModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    GetAD();
})

$('#ComplaintModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    GetAD();
});
```

and I can see the function gets called with any one on shown or hidden but the new value is not there and I can also see the value on the for loop array. if I refresh the page the new option is there. If I get the select element outside the modal everything works. any ideas?

This is how the HTML looks on the browser:

```
                        <select tabindex="-98" title="Choose one of the following origin..." class="form-control" id="ADSelect">
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="44">44</option>
                        <option value="555">555</option>
                        <option value="test8">test8</option>
                        <option value="555555">555555</option>
                         <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
                        <option value="test4">test4</option>
                        <option value="test6">test6</option>
                        <option value="test7">test7</option>
                    </select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the output HTML i.e. the entire select element after "baking".

Comment: @WebDevBooster posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue I was using Bootstrap-select JQuery plugin that need a .selectpicker('refresh') to update the UI to match the new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple and silly thing! Thanks for posting the solution. Even just selectpicker() didnt work. 'refresh' is the key :)